# Trying to insert data to multiple table with the last table `student` being the child table. Data is inserted to the other tables except the parent

Tags: mysql

```
  BEGIN;
  INSERT INTO `address` (`postal address`, `email`, `phone_number`) VALUES ('1527', 'tommydd@gmail.com', '0766452152');
  INSERT INTO `bank` (`bank_number`, `bank_name`,`branch`) VALUES ('050002345678', 'Equity', 'Haniwa');
  INSERT INTO `fees` (`perannum`, `fee_balance`) VALUES ('27000', '1500.34');
  INSERT INTO `institution` (`Institution_name`, `course`, `form_study_year`, `adm_upi`, `type`) VALUES ('KU', 'Computer Science', '3rd Year', 'STT/B/01-003/2009', 'Public Day');
  INSERT INTO `student` (`address_id`, `fees_id`, `bank_id`, `institution_id`, `first_name`, `middle_name`, `last_name`, `gender`, `date_of_birth`, `bc_no`, `parent`) VALUES ('LAST_INSERT_ID()', 'LAST_INSERT_ID()', 'LAST_INSERT_ID()', 'LAST_INSERT_ID()', 'Tommy', 'Gas', 'John', 'Male', '11/04/1999', '3868686', 'Both Alive');
  COMMIT;
```

Comment: How do you think `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is going to know which ID to use.  It will always be the last inserted ID for this connection, so in your case this will probably be the `institution_id`.

Comment: the linking must be the other way round. its address and fees must have the student_id property

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.